# Android Studio Java: Is it possible for a client who buys an Android app from me to change their API key?

Tags: java, android, api, api-key

I am currently developing on App in Android Studio (Java) for a client on Fiverr. I had that client sign up for a certain account and get an API key (since I didn't want to foot the bill for whenever the client uses the app). The client gave me the API key, but he asked me to make it easy for him to change the key in case he ever wants to get a new key later.

However, my concern is: Would it even be possible for me to adhere to this request? I mean, once I compile everything into an APK file, I had planned to simply give the APK file to the client so that the client could install it on his own Android phone. However, I don't think that he would be able to modify any of the app's code with just an APK file (let alone change the API key). Even if it is an installer file that I have to send instead of the APK itself, I doubt that the client would gain access to the code of the app itself.

That said, am I missing something? Is there any possible way for me to make it so that he could actually change the key, or does the client just not know what he is talking about?

Also, I know that sometimes API keys are set as environment variables, but this app is ultimately supposed to be installed on my client's phone. I doubt that my client's phone would have the same environment variables as my laptop (do phone's even have environment variables?).

What do I do here? The only thing I can really think of is to just deliver to the client the code itself along with the app so that if the client ever does want to change the key, he can just modify the appropriate line(s) of code and just recompile it himself.

Answer (score 0):

You could have him put the api key in a text file, then read that file from the app. You will have to add that functionality to the app though.

Data and file storage guide: [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#filesInternal)